# Get main frame window

Tags: c++, winapi, visual-c++, mdi, wtl

I want to get main frame window.
How to get main frame window in WTL-MDI?

```
class CChildFrame : public CMDIChildWindowImpl<CChildFrame>
{
    ...
    LRESULT OnEdit(WORD /*wNotifyCode*/, WORD /*wID*/, HWND /*hWndCtl*/, BOOL& bHandled)
    {
        ...
        mainfrm->FlashWindow(TRUE);
        return 1;
    }
}
```

Comment: You have project templates, which show you how. You should mentioned what you have tried. You need to show some code.

Answer (score 0):

The WTL base classes `CMDIChildWindowImpl`, `CFrameWindowImplBase` don't hold a pointer to main frame. It does not mean that you cannot do it yourself, you derive from these classes so you can pass the pointer explicitly as a part of initialization, and use it from there. After all you always have parent `HWND` in the child window class, so you can send an application defined message to exchange with certain information with the parent window.